# What's the point of Turnstile Polling mechanism of gRPC epoll1 polling engine?

Tags: sockets, c++11, grpc, epoll

I'm learning gRPC's implementation, and can't understand the design in [epoll1](https://github.com/legatoo/grpc/blob/master/doc/core/grpc-polling-engines.md#polling-engine-implementations) polling engine.

[image]

Based on the best practice from GRpc, users could create multiple CompleteQueues and each assigned a thread to it, this thread will `while(cq.Next())` to get work to do. The picture above comes from the official tutorial which indicates that in `epoll1`only one thread can actually call `epoll_wait` at a time.

My first question is GRpc uses `SO_REUSEPORT` to create socket `fd`, so the kernel will dispatch events to these `fds`, why not let these threads polling on `epoll_wait` independently? Why block each other on a condition variable? What's the tradeoff here?